# Can not retrieve data using json from web service for Android device via wifi

Tags: android, json

I am sending and retrieving data through an android device via wifi from localhost in my pc. But it is not retrieving data. log cat showing  JsonExeption, etc. here  i attached the log cat. below String tabledata is getting a null value.
Can you please suggest any solution.

```
String tabledata = getServerData("http://192.168.173.1:8077/Service1.svc/getTrainTimeTable?FromSt='"+frm+"'"+" ToSt= '" +t+ "'"+" FromTime= '" +t01+ "' "+"ToTime='"+t02+ "'"+" ArriveTime= '" +at+ "'"+" DepartTime= '" +dt+ "'"+" ReachingTime= '" +rt+ "'"+" TrainId= '"+tid+"'" );//send and retrieve request value

private String getServerData(String url) {// requet and response happens here
        String data = null;

        try {
            // Send GET request to <service>/GetPlates
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            // request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

            // Read response data into buffer
            char[] buffer = new char[(int) responseEntity.getContentLength()];
            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader.read(buffer);
            System.out.println(new String(buffer));

            stream.close();

            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
            data = (String) o.get("d");// create json object to decode from savedata();
            System.out.println(data);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return data;
    }
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: It looks like the server isn't sending any data. Have you checked the the server script is operating properly?

Comment: tnks for the rsponse. Webservice is working proerly. I used WCF service to send data. In there coudn't check properly json objects are sending. can you suggest a way to check it.